# Can not access javascript variable value

Tags: javascript

I can not access the value of msgdata outside getJSON().

```
  function editPost(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var msgdata = 'Hi';
        $.getJSON('/users', function (data) { 
                msgdata = prompt("Enter value");
        });
        var newMessage = { 'message': msgdata } 
     }
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Because, the GET request completed after newMessage assignment.